# Linked list- getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
void AlternatingSplit(struct Node* source, struct Node** aRef, 
                        struct Node** bRef) 
{
/* split the nodes of source to these 'a' and 'b' lists */
struct Node* a ; 
struct Node* b;

struct Node* current = source;
if(current){
    a=current;
    b=current->next;
    current=b->next;
    a->next=NULL;
    b->next=NULL;
}

while(current) {    
    a->next=current;
    b->next=current->next;

    if(b)
        current=b->next;

    b=b->next;
    a=a->next;
}

*aRef = a;
*bRef = b;
}
```

I am getting segmentaton fault here i dont know why pls help.

This question is to alternating split linkedlist nodes. I m using two pointers a and b and adding to it alternatingly but its giving error . pls help me

Comment: You need to provide an MCVE. But `b=current->next;current=b->next;` looks really suspect. If you don't have at least 3 nodes in the list you're in trouble.

Comment: Actually, if you don't have at least 2 nodes, and an even number of nodes, you are in trouble.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Many, most these days, development environments come with a debugging tool. Debuggers are the bee's knees. They allow you to control the execution of your program, executing it instruction by instruction if need be, and inspect the variables as you go. Very useful tool for finding out what a program is really doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your code -

- Trying to access node->next , without checking whether node exists or not .
- Not tackling the corner cases depending on the length of linked list (i.e. if length (linked list) < 3 )
- And then comes the blunder , you are trying to make the new linked lists and then in the end aRef and bRef is assigned to the last node in their respective linked lists.

Try to deal with these problems and for reference you can see the code below.

```
void AlternatingSplit(struct Node* source, struct Node** aRef, 
                    struct Node** bRef) 
{

struct Node* a,b; 
struct Node* current = source;

if(current){
       a=current;
       b=current->next;
       // moving 'current' one step at a time will secure the code from crashing for corner cases
       current = current->next;
       if(b)
             current=b->next;
       a->next=NULL;
       b->next=NULL;

       //link aRef bRef right here
       *aRef = a;
       *bRef = b;
       }

 else {
      *aRef = source; // Null
      *bRef = source; // Null
      return;
      }

while(current) 
{
     a->next=current;
     a=a->next;
     b->next=current->next;
     b=b->next;
     current=current->next;
     if(b){
          current = b->next;
          }
 }
 b->next = NULL;
 a->next = NULL;

}
```

Hope this will help .

Keep asking , keep growing :)

Comment: Unrelated. consistent indentation style helps detect bugs and keep programmers sane. This example seems to switch part way through from Ratliff indentation to Allman.

Comment: Wow ,that's something I didn't thought much of . Just realized that . Learnt something new after your comment . Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

Like most linked-list rearrangement exercises, pointers to pointers make the job *much*, much easier. The point of this exercise it to flex your ability to change the `next` pointers without ever changing the data values of said-same. Pointers to pointers are an excellent way to do that in C.

This is especially trivial because you were already provided the target pointer-to-pointer arguments that we can reuse for building each list. How that works is best understood by demonstrating a technique for building a forward-chained linked list using a single head pointer and a pointer to pointer `p`:

```
struct Node *head, **pp = &head;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i)
{
    *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
    (*pp)->data = i;
    pp = &(*pp)->next;
}
*pp = NULL;
```

Yes, it needs error checking, but the algorithm is what to focus on here. This code uses only `pp` to build the actual list. The rule is this: `pp` is a pointer to pointer to `Node`, and *always* holds the address of the next pointer to `Node` to populate. That's what pointers to pointers do: hold addresses of pointers. In this case `pp` initially holds the address of the head pointer. With each new node added `pp` takes the address of the `next` pointer of the previously just-added node. Makes sense, right? That will be the next pointer where we want to hang the next node. This process continues until we finish the loop. At that pointer `pp` holds the address of the *last* node's `next` pointer, which we set to `NULL` to terminate the list.

Now, knowing what we learned above, consider this:

```
void AlternatingSplit(struct Node* source, struct Node** a, struct Node** b)
{
    while (source)
    {
        *a = source;
        a = &(*a)->next;

        source = source->next;
        if (source)
        {
            *b = source;
            b = &(*b)->next;
            source = source->next;
        }
    }

    *a = *b = NULL;
}
```

**Example**

A short example using both the forward-chaining build algorithm I showed first, and the split algorithm I showed after, appears below. Some utility functions for printing the list are included. I leave freeing the lists (there are two now, remember to walk both and free each node) as an exercise for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void AlternatingSplit(struct Node* source, struct Node** a, struct Node** b)
{
    while (source)
    {
        *a = source;
        a = &(*a)->next;

        if ((source = source->next))
        {
            *b = source;
            b = &(*b)->next;
            source = source->next;
        }
    }

    *a = *b = NULL;
}

void PrintList(struct Node const *p)
{
    while (p)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    fputc('\n', stdout);
}


int main(void)
{
    struct Node *head, **pp = &head;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i)
    {
        *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
        (*pp)->data = i;
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }
    *pp = NULL;

    PrintList(head);

    struct Node *a = NULL, *b = NULL;
    AlternatingSplit(head, &a, &b);

    PrintList(a);
    PrintList(b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```